# Copy Content From One Element to Another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a image slider I'm using, each image has a caption below it, which looks a little like this.

```
<ul class="image-slider">
    <li>
      <img src="img-1.jpg">
      <figcaption>Fig1. - A view of the pulpit rock in Norway.</figcaption>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="img-2.jpg">
      <figcaption>Fig2. - A view of lighthouse.</figcaption>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Using a bit of jQuery, this image slider slides along, showing one image and their caption.

I've got a description box on my website where I want my caption to actually appear.

```
<div class="description">
  <h3>Image Gallery</h3>
  <p class="caption">This is where I want my caption to appear</p>
</div>
```

I can't use any absolute positioning or CSS, I need the caption text to move to across to the `p` tag using something else, possibly Javascript.

Is this possible?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you want all the captions to be displayed inside of that `p`

Comment: Yeah, but the slider is using `display: none;` on the hidden `li` so it only displays one image and one caption at any one time. So I'd like the `p` tag to update when the image changes.

Comment: can you show the code that you have done so far.?

Comment: Let me mock it up. I was thinking about using the jQuery append method. Give me a moment.

Comment: Okay, this is what I'm trying to do. See how the "This is caption 1" text doesn't change when the image changes? http://codepen.io/realph/pen/sJrnC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't this work?

```
$(".caption").text($('li:nth-child('+i+')').text());
```

where `i` is a variable (INT) that could get `i++` when moving forward in the image slider and get substracted by one (`i--`) when one goes one step back in the image slider.

Comment: Have you defined `i` before that line of code? `var i = 0; `

Comment: Works for me when I do it.

Comment: If you want to, I can help you integrate it into the image slider function.

Comment: Sure! If you think that would be best. http://codepen.io/realph/pen/sJrnC Thanks a lot! Feel free to fork the pen.

Comment: @realph quick question, do you plan on hosting the blueberry script on your server? It would make it a *lot* easier to integrate my code.

Comment: Yeah, I am using the script on my server. Are you saying you want to alter the blueberry script to make it easier? By all means do it if its easier.

Comment: I'm just going to add the line in the proper place in the script, ok?

Comment: Let me know when you've got a link. Thanks @Daniel Lisik!

Comment: You can just copy the script above the comment lines and put it in a .js file, I just had it inline to work with it :). Seems to work, let me now if it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you! That works great. I might make a separate js file, but this is great! Thanks again!

Comment: This may be a silly question, but what's the easiest way to put "Caption: " before the `.text()`?

Comment: You mean having it as beginning of every caption?

Comment: Yeah, so the rendered result will be `<p class="caption">Caption: This is caption 2.</p>`.

Comment: Find this line in the script `$(".caption").text($('.slides li:nth-child(1)').text());`, and replace it with `$(".caption").text('Caption: ' + $('.slides li:nth-child(1)').text());` Done! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot dude! I'm learning so much. Thanks for the comments too!